# How to get data from table using sub query in sql server 2008?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get data from tables using sub query, but i got this error :

Base table : [tblPriscription]

```
[Priscriptionid] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[patientId] [bigint] NULL,
[doctorId] [bigint] NULL,
[BillNo]  AS ([Priscriptionid]+(100)),
[BillDate] [datetime] NULL,
[BillType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PaymentBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[DocumentType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[DocumentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[bitIsActive] [bit] NULL,
[dateCreated] [date] NULL,
[bitIsDelete] [bit] NULL,
[bitisSave] [bit] NULL,
[TotalAmount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
```

A table from which i want to fetch data:

dbo.tblPriscriptionDetail

```
[PriscriptionDtlid] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Priscriptionid] [bigint] NULL,
[drugId] [bigint] NULL,
[Rxno] [bigint] NULL,
[sigId] [bigint] NULL,
[Selling] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[Qty] [int] NULL,
[RefillQty] [int] NULL,
[RefillNo] [int] NULL,
[Days] [int] NULL,
[Amount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[bitIsActive] [bit] NULL,
[dateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
[bitIsDelete] [bit] NULL,
[PurchaseDtlid] [bigint] NULL,
[bitIsSave] [bit] NULL,
[BillType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PaymentBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[patientId] [bigint] NULL,
[id] [bigint] NULL,
```

Qyery:

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT insuranceName
        FROM   tblinsurance
        WHERE  insuranceid = (SELECT insuranceid
                              FROM   tblpatient
                              WHERE  PatientId = tblPriscription.PatientId))            AS insuranceName,
       (SELECT drfirstname + ' ' + drlastname
        FROM   tbldoctor
        WHERE  doctorid = tblPriscription.doctorid)                                     AS doctorname,
       (SELECT patFirstName + ' ' + patLastName
        FROM   tblPatient
        WHERE  patientid = tblPriscription.patientid)                                   AS patname,
       (SELECT policyno
        FROM   tblPatient
        WHERE  patientid = tblPriscription.patientid)                                   AS policyno,
       (SELECT insuranceplanname
        FROM   tblInsurancePlan
        WHERE  insuranceplanid = (SELECT insuranceplanid
                                  FROM   tblpatient
                                  WHERE  PatientId = tblPriscription.PatientId))        AS insurancePlanName,
       (SELECT drugname
        FROM   tblDrugMaster
        WHERE  drugid = (SELECT drugid
                         FROM   tblPriscriptionDetail
                         WHERE  priscriptionid = tblPriscriptionDetail.priscriptionid)) AS drugname,
       (SELECT qty
        FROM   tblPriscriptionDetail
        WHERE  priscriptionid = tblPriscriptionDetail.priscriptionid)                   AS qty,
       (SELECT Selling
        FROM   tblPriscriptionDetail
        WHERE  priscriptionid = tblPriscriptionDetail.priscriptionid)                   AS selling
FROM   tblPriscription
```

i am trying to fetch data from tblPriscriptionDetail  drugname,qty and Selling suggest me, how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You simply need join not messy sub query.

```
  SELECT tp.*, tpd.qty, tpd.Selling, ti.insuranceName
    FROM tblPriscription tp inner join tblPriscriptionDetail tpd ON tpd.Priscriptionid = tp.Priscriptionid 
inner join tblinsurance ti ON ti.insuranceid  = tp.PatientId
inner join your other tables
```

Answer (score 0):

JOIN is the way to go, but beware of INNER JOINs unless you are sure there is always a matching record in each case - if not, then use [LEFT JOIN](https://www.quora.com/SQL-What-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)s. If you are sure INNER JOINs won't lose rows, then try this

```
SELECT Selling, qty, drugname, insuranceplanname, policyno, patFirstName + ' ' + patLastName AS patname, drfirstname + ' ' + drlastname AS doctorname, insuranceName
FROM tblPrescription P
INNER JOIN tblPrescriptionDetail PD ON PD.PrescriptionID = P.PrescriptionID
INNER JOIN tblDrugMaster DM ON DM.PrescriptionID = PD.PrescriptionID
INNER JOIN tblPatient PP ON PP.PatientID = P.PatientID
INNER JOIN tblInsurancePlan IP ON IP.InsuranceplanID = P.InsuranceplanID
INNER JOIN tblDoctor D ON D.DoctorID = P.DoctorID
INNER JOIN tblInsurance I ON I.InsuranceID = P.InsuranceID
```

I have tried to introduce some consistency in capitalisation, and have included all the fields you were extracting in your original (rather than just the ones you say you want). I'm curious that you have both tblInsurance and tblInsurancePlan.